# How to print remaining time in time sleep in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

there is sample of code

```
 print ("run some code  line here")
 time.sleep(100) # print remaining time for example 35 sec left
```

I want to try print the remaining time live or after (x sec ) of sleep time

there is any way to do this ?  it's possible

Comment: How often/when do you wan't to print the remaining time?

Comment: The program is not running during that time. You can simulate the effect with threads, but you will need to check how much time has elapsed and do the math yourself.

Comment: CutePoison , ,it's depends if i have 10800 sec i want every 500 sec show me leaft time

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import time


def sleep(num):
    for i in range(num):
        print("\rTime remaining: {} seconds.".format(num - i), end='')
        time.sleep(1)


sleep(100)
```

Comment: thank you , but what if in case didn't use looop ?

Comment: good idea, know i understood

Answer (score 0):

**use this function:**

```py
import time
def time_left(sleep_time, step=1):
    for _ in range(sleep_time, 0, (-1)*step):
        print('\r{} sec left'.format(_), end='')
        time.sleep(step)
```

`sleep_time` is the time you expect to set the sleep and `step` is for the step you want to go forward and the default is `1sec`

and finally, use it in your loop:

```py
for i in range (5):
    print (i)
    time_left(100)
```

Comment: thank you , but what if in case didn't use looop ?

Comment: it's the same you can use this function `time_left()` where ever you want it doesn't matter you use loop or not.

Comment: time.sleep(step) it's take 100 sec also